# Best practice to customize MUI 5 Drawer without CSS overriding

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am learning how to customize MUI 5 components by using as much theming and props and relying less on CSS overrides (which if used a lot defeats the pros of MUI)

First, I provided my own theme

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: "light",
    primary: {
      main: "#12131c",
      contrastText: "#fcfcfc",
    },
  },
});
```

But this theme doesn't apply to the `<Drawer>` component which stays white, but only to the `<AppBar>` component

[image]

Adding `sx` override to `<Drawer>` didn't change anything

```
<Drawer
  sx={{ bgcolor: "primary.main", color: "primary.contrastText" }}
>
  <nav>
    <List>
      <ListItem disablePadding>
        <ListItemButton>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <InfoIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
        </ListItemButton>
      </ListItem>
      ...
```

In another SO answer, they suggested adding

```
<Drawer          
   PaperProps={{
      sx: {
        bgcolor: "primary.main",
        color: "primary.contrastText",
      },
   }}
>
```

Which works better, but it doesn't get applied to `<ListItemIcon>` and I lose the List Item color change when hovering.

[image]

I could go about adding `sx` overrides to all those components to get to the style I want, but I feel this defeats the purpose. Is there a better way I should be using and taking advantage of MUI's system? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/

U might want something like this: (in your theme)

```
    palette: {...},
    components: {
        MuiDrawer: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: ({ theme }) => ({
                    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
                    color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
                }),
            },
        },
    }
```